# Including a pseudo chapter in the table of contents

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents

I have all  parts of my thesis (introduction/body/results ) etc. in the table of contents. Right before the introduction I have an image (on a separate page) which currently has no title. I have been asked to give it a title/heading such that it gets included in the table of contents. I dont want to make it a chapter. How can I include it in the table of contents?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add in the preamble of your document

```
\providecommand\phantomsection{}% for hyperref
```

Then before the picture

```
\clearpage
% Add the title here, maybe \chapter*{My image title} ????
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{My image title}
%Your image here ....
```

Comment: The `\providecommand\phantomsection{}` is not needed if someone uses `hyperref`, isn't it?

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: It is nessesary if you use `hyperref` to put an anchor position. Without `\phantomsection` hyperref will jump to the previous sectioning position.

Comment: I understand the need of `\phantomsection`, but my point is: If you use `\usepackage{hyperref}` you don't need to add the `\providecommand\phantomsection{}` line. So simply commenting the `\phantomsection` line with "Needed if hyperref is used" would be actually clearer, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: My view is it good practise to always put `\phantomsection` before all `\addcontentslines`. If you add `hyperref` later then you do not have to change anything.  Therefor the `\providecommand` to always provide it.